# Making ee.data.authenticationViaAuth always success

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to Google earth engine. I am using earth engine javascript api (ee_api_js.js).

```
var onImmediateFailed = function() {
    ee.data.authenticateViaPopup(function() {
      runAnalysis();
    });
};
ee.data.authenticateViaOauth(CLIENT_ID, runAnalysis, null, null, onImmediateFailed);
```

When I run it the first time on any browser it always goes to "onImmediateFailed". I am not sure what settings needs to be done in order to always succeed while executing this.

I am creating a web app where users will navigate to earth engine functions and I don't want user to have to login to their Google account.

Comment: As shown in the comment [here](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/e2fb3571793f527c014b3db6f7c971f9cf827e48/javascript/src/data.js#L80) this will always fail unless the user is already authenticated.  Either your app has to authenticate (via service account) or your user does.  If it's the former, then use `ee.ServiceAccountCredentials()`.  If it's the latter, then you have no choice but to let the user login.

Comment: Is there any reference how to use ee.ServiceAccountCredentials() ?
that would be great help.
Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/app_engine_intro#2-set-up-credentials

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you solved this already, but this might be because the browsers are blocking the pop up to choose an google account.

Link to documentation:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-data-authenticateviaoauth